# "Buy the farm" meaning

Tags: meaning, idioms, connotation, lyrics

In Alice Cooper’s song “Hey Stoopid” from his 1991 album, there is a verse that runs like this:

> Now I know you’ve been kicked around.
>     You ain’t alone in this ugly town.
>     You stick a needle in your arm.
>     You bite the dust, **you buy the farm.**

How can anybody, a junkie apparently, “buy the farm” when he is giving up in life?

What does the verbal phrase *to buy the farm* mean or connote in contemporary English?

Comment: Welcome to ELU!  This is an excellent place to ask questions like this.  And, this was a good question.  The one critique would be that we ask for you to google first, ask second.  So, an idiom like this would be easily googled for meaning, the origin might not be so easy.

Comment: Never occurred to me that this is an idiom, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To "buy the farm" is simply an American expression meaning to die.  Not used as frequently now as it was a few decades ago.

Comment: Thanks! Never occurred to me. I was thinking about this for years. What is the origin of the expression?

Comment: http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-buy1.htm claims it comes from US Air Force slang in the 1950's, and they modified it from earlier British pilot expressions.

Comment: FWIW, _bite the dust_ means the same thing. See also _kick the bucket_. Apparently, there are many ways farm-related ways to die.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins If you *buy the plot* you can spend your time *pushing up daisies*, *taking a dirt nap* and *going for a Burton*.